# Seeking Assistance: "Login with Facebook" Activation Issue in Laravel React Integration

Tags: reactjs, laravel, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I am working on integrating the "Login with Facebook" feature into my Laravel React website. I have properly configured my application within the Facebook Developer portal, ensuring that the meta developer account settings are accurate.

However, upon clicking the "Login with Facebook" link, I encounter the following error on the Facebook login page:

Error Message:
"App not active
This app is not accessible right now, and the app developer is aware of the issue. You will be able to log in when the app is reactivated."

This issue seems to indicate that there might be an activation problem with my Facebook application. I have verified that the configurations are correct in the Facebook Developer portal. Is there a specific step I might be missing, or is there a known resolution for this type of error?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully enable the "Login with Facebook" functionality on my Laravel React website. Thank you!

Comment: Typically when you click login with facebook, you would need to enter login credentials or if the current session already has a login facebook account, it should execute the calback function for you to `retrieve` the user information from meta.

Comment: How did you setup your "login with facebook" feature? With Socialite? When users click login, did it reach your call back method?

Comment: If not, then there is a problem with how you setup your meta settings. (maybe missing keys or settings not properly setup).

Comment: Yes, I do both redirection to facebook login page and login callback in  laravel backend using laravel/socialite package. And I am sure I set the keys like client id, client secret and redirect url correctly.

Comment: Did it reach your callback method? (where you are fetching user info, getting/saving meta id, etc)? If not then there is a problem with your settings.

Comment: No, the callback will be called after the user form submition, but now the facebook login page is not displayed correctly and I have my issue on it.

Comment: Update your question with the callback. Since you said that the callback was actually called, also include which part of the code did it have an error. Add complete stack